# What is the proper way to convert Tracing Code using RunOptions to Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm having difficulty finding any documentation on how to migrate tracing code from 1.x to 2.0.

In tensorflow 1.x you could do the following:

```
run_options = tf.compat.v1.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.compat.v1.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
final_result = sess.run(result, feed_dict={...},
                        options=run_options,
                        run_metadata=run_metadata)

trace = fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()
with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(chrome_trace)
```

How can you do a similar thing with a @tf.function call?

```
@tf.function
def predict(x1, x2):
    ...
#=============
# Set run options and RunMetadata variables
#=============
#=============
final_result = predict(x1_val, x2_val)

#=============
# Dump Trace (assuming run_metadata is the RunMetaData object we configured previously)
#=============
trace = fetched_timeline = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
chrome_trace = fetched_timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()
with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(chrome_trace)
#=============
```